# What is the most efficient way to read from a template text file and then write interpolated values from different variables from a script?

Tags: python, string-interpolation

I have a Python script that I want to output with a README.txt files for users. In the README.txt, there are going to be some description of what was run in the script, including the values. The values of these variables change depending on the project. Since the README.txt file is kind of long, and copying and pasting values to multiple README.txt files is time consuming, I wanted to create and quick and easy function that would read in a template README.txt file and then interpolate the correct values in their appropriate places, creating a new, pertinent README.txt file.

So an example snippet from the README.txt template would read as:

```
In this script, we ran the statistical processes with variable A set to {variableA} and variable B set to {variableB}. 

We also used the following comparisons where we examined group {group1} vs group {group2}.
```

I have placed the curly brackets to indicate where I want variables from my script (i.e. variableA, variableB, group1, and group2) so their values are interpolated into the correct places. But I am not certain how best I should format my README.txt template and set it up to efficiently take in the values of the relevant variables. All these variables are defined globally, so scope should not be a problem here.

So far my code reads:

```
with open("README_template.txt") as readme:
    readme = readme.readlines()
    readme_new = []
    for line in readme:
          #interpolate the pertinent values into the line if necessary
          readme_new.append(line)
    #write out new README.txt file
```

Comment: Read the whole file and use `.format()` to pass values for placeholders. But better would be to use template engine like `jinja2`

Comment: @buran I'm looking into jinja2 now, but it seems somewhat complicated for what I need. If I were to use `.format()` like you suggested, how would that be integrated into the template README.txt file? Like, would I have `{variableA}` literally written in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template.txt

```
In this script, we ran the statistical processes with variable A set to {variableA} and variable B set to {variableB}. 
We also used the following comparisons where we examined group {group1} vs group {group2}.
```

your script:

```
data = {'variableA':'A', 'variableB':'B',
        'group1':1, 'group2':2}

with open('template.txt', 'r') as f, open('README.txt', 'w') as fout:
    templ = f.read()
    fout.write(templ.format(**data))
```

resulting README.txt

```
In this script, we ran the statistical processes with variable A set to A and variable B set to B. 
We also used the following comparisons where we examined group 1 vs group 2.
```

Now, if you change your template.txt to

```
In this script, we ran the statistical processes with variable A set to {{variableA}} and variable B set to {{variableB}}. 
We also used the following comparisons where we examined group {{group1}} vs group {{group2}}.
```

and your script to:

```
import jinja2

data = {'variableA':'A', 'variableB':'B',
        'group1':1, 'group2':2}

tmpl_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath='.')
tmpl_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=tmpl_loader)
template = tmpl_env.get_template('template.txt')
with open('README1.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(template.render(**data))
```

you can get the same. HOWEVER, jinja2, as template engine provides powerful tools to generate the output file (e.g. loops, conditionals, filters, etc.) in comparisons with simple string formatting `.format()`

Comment: I have been trying to follow your instructions, but I keep getting `TemplateNotFound` error every time. I have tried to look up solutions to this problem, but none of the solutions I have found work at this point. I have my file path to my README template file properly set in both the FileSystemLoader() and tmpl_env.get_template(), so I'm not sure what it is I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If you get the error, then it is not properly set. One reason - you use wrong relative path. The other option - you need to set the path to folder where template in search path. Then in `get_tempalte()` you specify the template (without path)

Comment: Ok, now I got it working! Sorry, it was not intuitive to me at all that the FileSystemLoader needed a relative path. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It can be absolute or relative, what I meant was that maybe you use incorrect relative path

Comment: Odd, I thought that I was definitely using the right absolute path, but maybe there was some kind of typo.

Comment: Here is link [to docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.FileSystemLoader) _The path can be relative or absolute. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory._